# AngularJS ui-router - overwrite child data in parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have setup parent and child states using ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
    .state( 'profilePage', {
        url: '/u/:user',
        templateUrl: 'app/user/profilePage/profilePage.html',
        data: {tab:'default'}
    })
    .state( 'profilePage.tracks', {
        url: '/tracks',
        templateUrl: 'app/user/profilePage/profilePage.tracks.html',
        data: {tab:'tracks'}
    });
```

when i navigate from tracks

```
/u/someuser/tracks
```

to another user's parent profile

```
/u/otheruser
```

the tab.data property is not reset to 'default' as expected. it stays as 'tracks' from the previous state. debugging the state shows that it is definitely using the 'profilePage' state and not a child state but the data.tab value is not overwritten. it seems that parent states are not allowed to overwrite the data field once a child state has written it. frustrating and unexpected behavior.

using the $stateChangeStart event i can force the desired change. however the solution is disorganized and forces the scattering of related code. i believe expected behavior would be for the data.tab value to be set when the state config is setting it.

Comment: Can you share the code where you retrieving the ``data`` ??

Comment: `if( $state.current.data.tab == 'default' )
{
     ...
}`

Comment: Same problem here. I have an abstract root state with `data.someboolean` which is `false` per default. now if one of the various childs sets it to `true` it will be `true` everywhere instead of just this child.

Ill tell you as soon as I find a solution do this.